# When passing a collection, only the first element seems to be passed

Tags: javascript, jira

I am using my code to get data from JIRA. JIRA server returns a set of elements (called issues), and this works perfectly fine:

```
for (let issue of JiraIssues) {..processing code } //this works well, I get all the issues
```

However, when I wanted to separate the code getting the data from the code processing it, I cannot figoure out how to pass the JiraIssues correctly:

```
Processing(JiraIssues) //calling the function

function Processing(jiraIssues) //fucntion signature
```

The thing is, what is passed into the function seems to be just the first element.

Comment: Have you inspected `JiraIssues` to see what kind of data it holds?

Comment: @OliverRadini Yes, it a set of elements, where each also holds an array. But what gets passed is just the very first record.

Comment: Can you add the code segment how you got the JiraIssues. The problem might be that the API gets only the first found.

Comment: @ZoltánJére No, it works fine in the original function, I get 300 elements. When I pass the result using the code above, there is suddenly just the first.

Comment: could you provide us with, a snapshot of how jiraissues looks? maybe even pseudo data would work. but having a look at the response would help

Comment: @AkhilArjun I will try to get them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function processOneIssue(issue) {
        console.log(issue); // logs one issue
    }
    function processAllIssues(issueList) {
        console.log(issueList); // logs the list with all the issues
    }

    JiraIssues.forEach((issue) => {
        this.processOneIssue(issue);
    });
    this.processAllIssues(JiraIssues);
```

I am not sure if I understand your problem. But this two little function should do what you need. Make sure you are calling them in the right place. It is possible that you are overwriting the original JiraIssues inside the loop with one of the element. Try using different less familiar variable names for testing purposes.

UPDATE based on the comment:

```
//// file1
export function processOneIssue(issue) {
    console.log(issue); // logs one issue
}
export function processAllIssues(issueList) {
    console.log(issueList); // logs the list with all the issues
}

////// file 2
import * as file1 from 'path1'; 

JiraIssues.forEach((issue) => {
    file1.processOneIssue(issue);
});
file1.processAllIssues(JiraIssues);
```

There should be no diffrence just because the import.

Comment: Thanks, it works in the same file. But when I place the function to another JS file (that is included via Import), only the first element is passed.